# how to disable jsTree node renaming?

Tags: jquery, jstree

When creating a new node I set its name.

I want to not allow the user to rename the node after creation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using the [CRRM](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm) plugin.

If you look at the signature for `create`, you'll see the last parameter lets you skip the user input step during the creation process:

```
.create ( node , position , js , callback , skip_rename )
```